# How to remove gradient / drop shadow for UITabbaritem in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

with iOS 5, there is UI Appearance, is it possible to remove the gradient easy way ?

i do this to customised my tabbar, what can be done to remove the gradient ?

thanks for reading

```
-(void)UIAppearances
{
    //set the background of tab bar
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bgrd.png"]];

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] > 4.9) {
        //iOS 5
        //[self.tabBarController.tabBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:1];

        [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bgrd.png"]];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbaractive.png"]];


        [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          [UIColor colorWithRed:75.0/255.0 green:75.0/255.0 blue:75.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
          [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
          [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
          nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
          [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
          [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
          nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];   


        //nav bar
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: 
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Rokkitt" size:28.0],
          UITextAttributeFont,
          nil]];
    }
    else {
        //iOS 4.whatever and below
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];

    }   

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UITabBar can either take an image and use its alpha channel (opacity) to build the selected/unselected images or take two processed images to use as is.

You'll have to provide the images yourself to the UITabBarItem with [`setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/setFinishedSelectedImage%3awithFinishedUnselectedImage%3a). There's no other way to affect the processing it does to the images besides changing the color of the gradient with UITabBar's [`selectedImageTintColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/selectedImageTintColor) appearance property.

Comment: u can use it only ios 5 and newer

Comment: @lesyk: Correct. I linked to the documentation which also says that, which is why I didn't mention it. I have no idea how to achieve this before iOS because I haven't looked into it; maybe you subclass UITabBar, maybe you build your own.